# VBScript: Error 10023 in : Array index out of range (trouble when reusing an array variable)

Tags: arrays, vbscript, sax

Using Sax ActiveX Scripting (long story), I have 3 nested if statements which reuse the same return variable. Script looks roughly like:

```
Dim rtnArray As Variant
If variable1 <> "" Then
    ' Perform SQL query against DB2 database
    rtnArray = DB2SQLSearch(Query)
    If UBound(rtnArray) = 0 Then
        ' ditto
        rtnArray = DB2SQLSearch(Query2)
        MsgBox "Gets this far"
        If UBound(rtnArray) = 0 Then ' Error!
            ' Never make it here
```

What's odd is that this same code structure is working in a script I wrote last week; I simply changed a couple of the queries and the name of the function (find > replace).

After the 2nd query, I've tried a `MsgBox CStr(rtnArray(0)(0))` but it yields `Error 10025 in : Array has a different number of indexes.`

Error codes correspond to the following manual:
http://www.ftgsoftware.com/manuals/basic32.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In this particular case, the user that I was connecting as had authorization to the first table, but not the second.

This did not throw an error, but there is a message I can check to see whether there was a success or not, so I can look for that and throw my own error, instead of passing back a null array. (it's not a proper `Null`, frankly I'm still not 100% sure what it is, aside from a `Variant`. But it sure doesn't like `UBound()`!

Comment: FYI: In normal VBScript, UBound fails on empty arrays that are declared as `Dim arr()` (see http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/default.aspx/McNeel/RsEmptyArray). Maybe this is the case.

Comment: I declared mine as a Variant; see the code above.
Interesting article; I'll have to play around with it and see how much of it holds true for Sax.

Answer (score 0):

You can either store it in another variable, or `ReDim` the rtnArray variable to havve the proper size.  In order to Redim, you need to know the size.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's for query results; I don't know how large it'll be, so I don't know that ReDim will work.

In the course of debugging I've tried creating a second array variable just for that inner query, but I get the same errors.